# Redbean: does addDatabase immediately connect to said database?

Tags: php, orm, redbean

Simple question, does the following command automatically connect to the given database?

R::addDatabase('DB1','sqlite:/tmp/d1.sqlite','user','password',$frozen);

Or does it wait until you actually try to perform a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no connection is made automatically if you add the database.  When you use `R::selectDatabase('DB1');` a connection is attempted and an error is thrown if the connection can't be made.  You have probably figured all this out already though...